# Make ignores existing rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this simply GNU Make file:

```
# Bibliografia
BIBLIO = referencies/biblio.bib
CSL = referencies/acm-mod.csl
TMPATOM = plantilles/entorn.pandoc.atom.html

# Variables
PANDOC_MD_ATOM = pandoc --webtex --smart --from=markdown+auto_identifiers+table_captions+simple_tables+pipe_tables+strikeout+tex_math_dollars+raw_html+footnotes+inline_notes+citations+implicit_figures --to=html5 --bibliography=$(BIBLIO) --csl=$(CSL) --filter pandoc-citeproc --metadata link-citations=true --template=$(TMPATOM)

ERB = erb -T 1

# Què processar
MARKDOWN_YAML_ATOM=$(shell ruby ./select.rb 'atom')
MARKDOWN_ATOM=$(MARKDOWN_YAML_ATOM:.md=.md.atom.html)

all: $(MARKDOWN_ATOM)

%.md.atom.html: %.md %.md.meta $(TMPATOM)
    $(ERB) $< | $(PANDOC_MD_ATOM) -V filename=$< $<.meta -o $@
```

When I run `make` I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'blog/Aitor-theorem.md.atom.html', needed by 'all'.  Stop
```

but clearly it is a rule for files `.md.atom.html`.

Answer (score 1):

When make wants to build a target `blog/Aitor-theorem.md.atom.html` and there's no explicit rule for that, it will look for a rule to match that target.

When it looks at your pattern rule it will match with a stem (the part that matches the `%`) of `Aitor-theorem` and a directory prefix of `blog/`.  So, when it constructs the patterns for the prerequisites it will use those same values for the stem and directory; that is, make will check to see if the targets `blog/Aitor-theorem.md` and `blog/Aitor-theorem.md.meta` (and of course `plantilles/entorn.pandoc.atom.html`) either already exist or can be made by using other pattern rules.

The error you're seeing means that `make` couldn't figure out how to build one or more of those prerequisites.  When that happens, `make` can't use this pattern rule (it doesn't match) so it will go looking for a different pattern rule to use.  If there is no other pattern rule, then it will give this error "No rule to make target", because there is no matching rule.

Since you haven't told us what the actual files you have available and expect to be used are named, we can't advise you further.

You can run `make -d` to see a complete trace of all the steps `make` invokes to try to build your target (there's a lot of output so redirect it to a file or something).

Comment: Perhaps a bad encoding?